# Mysql replace() function, help with query (what chars do I escape?)

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update an old cms where images were stored in /images/editor/, they are now stored in a bucket on amazon s3. I'm trying to update the database using mysql replace. I've done this in the past with replacing simple words, but now Mysql is reporting an error, I suspect because this is more than a simple word:

```
UPDATE contents SET desc = replace(desc, 
'/images/editor/', 
'http://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/editor/')
```

Do I need to escape the : or slashes? I've tried escaping it with a '\' to no avail. Can someone get me pointed in the right direction? Thanks!

**Edit**

Here's the error I am getting, nothing too telling

> error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc = replace(desc, '/images/editor', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/app_navigator/ed' at line 1

Comment: Isn't `desc` a reserved word? BTW, `select replace('my/images/editor/gamma', '/images/editor/', 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket/editor/');` works. Are you sure `select count(*) from contents where description like '%/images/editor/%'` returns non zero value?

Comment: +1 it is a reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nothing to do with the escape (ie. nothing need to be escaped),
but you need to quote the reserved keyword `desc`

so,

```
UPDATE contents SET `desc` = replace(`desc`, ...
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize this was a reserved word. When using the single quotes I am still getting the same error. The query does work on another column, though.

Comment: @jyoseph - use back-tick "`", or ANSI double quote (mostly people use back-tick)